# add_rewrite_rule() not working

Tags: rewrite-rules

I need to pass a property reference the last part of a URL to search the database for an entry, eg,

> http://example.com/cottage-details/G638/

I need to pass the G638 into an array for my plugin. What I have below is calling the cottage-details page, but removing the last part of the URL and showing an empty page, rather than the information I wish to retrieve from the server. If I use

> http://example.com/cottage-details/?propref=G638

it works perfectly.

```
/**
 * Rewrite tags for plugin
 */
function dcc_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%propref%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_tags', 10, 0);

/**
 * Rewrite rules for plugin 
 */
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^[^/]*/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=2&propref=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

What’s going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You rewrite rule is quite broad and will most likely generate a lot of conflicts.

```
add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_tags');
function dcc_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%propref%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^cottage-details/(.+)/?$','index.php?page_id=2&propref=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Then you can access to `propref` query var like:

```
$propref = get_query_var( 'propref' );
```

And remember to flush the rewrite rules; you can do it by going to Settings -> Permalinks and clicking on save button.

**Note**: changed `p` query var to `page_id` because, as you said in the comments, you are using a page, not a standard post.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the many combinations I've tried. Doesn't work either. I've downloaded this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ and it's showing that the rule's correct and everything *should* be okay, but for some reason, it's not.

Comment: It works here. Can you be more specific about "it's not working"? Do you get HTTP error? can not get `propref` query var? Any other issue?

Comment: A vardump() of the array shows it's empty *viz*: 
`array(2) { ["propref"]=> string(0) "" ["brand"]=> string(2) "ZZ" }`

Comment: I can only think I'm not calling it correctly, I'm using `$values['propref'] = get_query_var( "propref" );`

Comment: Should Wordpress be writing the rule to .htaccess as there's no additional rules in there beyond the default rules? I'm sure the rewrite is correct, it's almost as if it's not actually being implemented by Apache.

Comment: .htaccess is not involved in this. I've tested again a it is working.

Comment: Well, it's not working on my installation!

Comment: What is `cottage-details`? a page or post? Which is its ID?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this. It's a page, ID is 2.

Comment: If it is a page, the rewrite rule must use `page_id` instead or `p`. See [WP Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). I've editred the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it using pagename instead of p.

Comment: Great. `page_id` or `pagename` will work, the key is that you need to query a page, not a standard post. If this answer fixs your problem, please, mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can not thank you enough, this finally worked for me. The trick is also to refresh the permalink cache ALWAYS